# How to publish C# Gdal project to Debian

Tags: c#, linux, gdal

I have a .NET Core C# web project which uses GDAL and GDAL.Native packages. All works well locally, but after publishing to a Debian server, it reports a bunch of messages like

> /usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/8.0.0/osr_wrap.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
> /var/www/appRoot/osr_wrap.so: cannot open shared object file

My gitlab script is:

```yaml
build-backend:
  stage: build-backend
  image: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:latest
  script:
    - cd appDir
    - dotnet restore
    - dotnet build --configuration Release
    - rsync -av --delete bin/Release/net8.0/ /var/www/appRoot/
```

Other components of the project work well after publishing. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a brief look and from memory - the NuGet GDAL and GDAL.Native packages only work on Windows since they do not package the binaries for other platforms (and there are a lot of binaries needed).

This is also shown by the error message calling for osr_wrap.so - if it was a multiplatform build it would be asking for libosr_wrap.so.

The other available sources for C# are shown here https://gdal.org/api/csharp/index.html.

I created and use the Conda package since I needed it for Unity and that does not use NuGet anyway. The other option you have - I believe  - is the MaxRev solution.

Comment: MaxRev solution is the right way to go. Nuget packages MaxRev,Gdal.Core, MaxRev.Gdal.WindowsRuntime.Minimal and MaxRev.Gdal.LinuxRuntime.Minimal. After publishing with script above, had to cp /var/www/appRoot/runtimes/linux-x64/native/maxrev.gdal.core.libshared/proj.db /var/www/appRoot/

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are missing at least one shared object. It is likely that you are missing more. I know little about the C#/gdal bindings, but all of the various language bindings (outside of c/c++) require a binding layer that the higher level language (C# in your case) can call that in turn invokes the needed GDAL functionality. A trivial search turns up this:

```
gdal_csharp.dll
ogr_csharp.dll
osr_csharp.dll
gdalconst_csharp.dll
gdal_wrap.dll
ogr_wrap.dll
osr_wrap.dll
gdalconst_wrap.dll
```

I am going to assume that the debian install will require the equivalent .so wrappers